# replace char in specific pattern or after specific character

Tags: java, regex, string

The task at hand is to replace "-" with "/" in a birthday format e.g. `03-12-89 -> 03/12/89`. However, the "-" must be able to appear elsewhere in the string e.g. "My-birthday-is-on-the: 03/12/89".

I have tried creating substrings, replace the "-" in the birthday part and then combine the strings again. However, that solution is inflexible and fails the testcases.

I'm thinking I must be able to do this with a regular expression, although I seem unable to construct it. So now I'm back to: `String newStr = input.replace("-", "/");` Which remove all instances of "-" which I don't want.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Use a regular expression to find the birthday, then only replace the characters within that match range

Comment: @MadProgrammer that's what I want, but how?

Comment: You can parse dates to find they are dates, and then apply regex only to them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way which comes to mind is just match `\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}`, with capture groups.  Then, use those captured numbers to rebuild the birthdate the way you want it.  Something like this:

```
String input = "My-birthday-is-on-the: 03/12/89";
input = input.replaceAll("\\b(\\d{2})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2})\\b", "$1/$2/$3");
```

### Demo

The advantage of specifying the full pattern is that it avoids the chance of matching anything other than a 6 digit dash-separated birthday.

**Edit:**

Based on your comment below, it sounds like maybe you want to do this replacement on a two dash separated number, with any number of digits.  In this case, we can slightly modify the above code to the following:

```
String input = "Your policy number is: 123-45-6789.";
input = input.replaceAll("\\b(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)\\b", "$1/$2/$3");
```

Comment: Inside the my method:

private static String changeFormat(String input) {
 String newStr = input.replaceAll("\\b(\\d{2})-(\\d{2})-(\\d{2})\\b", "$1/$2/$3");
  return newStr;
}

The output is still the same as the input. I don't get it (i have accounted for the wrong input in your example.)

Comment: @Kenneth I don't know your code.  Try to start with my demo, or the other answer, and go from there.

Comment: Code is simple: call this method: System.out.println(changeFormat("Your policy number is: 123-45-6789."));

With the above implementation

Comment: I love you :) Thank you SO much. Code works. I'll analyse to see why and learn something from it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?<=\d{2})-
```

with replacement `\/` (no need to escape it in Java)

**INPUT:**

```
My-birthday-is-on-the: 03-12-89
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
My-birthday-is-on-the: 03/12/89
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/86gchj/1/)

**Code:**

```
String input = "My-birthday-is-on-the: 03-12-89";
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("(?<=\\d{2})-", "/"));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
My-birthday-is-on-the: 03/12/89
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: You are right for the escape part thanks ;-)

Comment: It works the way you made it, but inside my method it doesn't? Any idea why?
´private static String changeFormat(String input) {
  String newStr = input.replace("(?<=\\d{2})-", "/");
  
  return newStr;
 }´
newStr is the same as the input string

Comment: @Kenneth: this is normal the method should be `replaceAll` and not `replace` as described in my answer